# How to remove Unicode String Java

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I have written a Springboot app that reads from DynamoDB and generates a XML. In one of the items in the table, there is a field that has the string '\u0019'. This is a unicode string that denotes End Of Medium. Please refer to the screenshot below to see how it looks in DynamoDB. [image]

The Springboot app reads it. With IntelliJ, I inspected the variable that holds this value. It looks like this[image]

When I write this value to an XML, the XML tag looks like this. [image]

There is another program that is trying to parse this XML. It fails complaining

```
XML character (Unicode: 0x19) at lineNumber: ___ ; columnNumber: ___ ;
```

I want to check if a string contains a Unicode string. If it contains, I want to remove the same. I tried using

- Apache library:StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(test2)
- replaceAll("\P{Print}", "");

The problem with these, is that they remove also characters like **é**. For example: L'Oréal becomes L'Oral OR LOral

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: all characters are unicode. "Remove all unicode"? Okay.. `String s ="";`, there you go. Perhaps you mean 'remove all control characters'?

Comment: I want to remove Unicode String that denotes the unicode as you can see from the screenshot.

Comment: When you say the 'field' has the 'string' \u0019, is that one character or six characters?  This is vital to know.  In the first case, you've got one character (in Unicode because that's all Java knows in strings) and it's a control character; in the second case you've got six (all Unicode!) characters that form a recognizable sequence, starting with backslash,'u' that you could easily scan for.  But please get out of the habit of thinking that only some characters in Java are Unicode.

Comment: you want to remove 0x19 specifically? `char c = 0x19; String cc = "" + c; input.replace(cc, "");`

Comment: Such control characters are either valid or invalid. If they are invalid why are they there?. If they are valid then they should be reflected in your XML. In order to be part of the XML they should be in a CDATA section

Comment: @rzwitserloot No, I don't want just to remove 0x19. But I want to remove anything string literal that denotes a Unicode. Also, 0x19 is the hexadecimal representation of  \u0019

Comment: @g00se I don't have control over the data being pushed into DynamoDB. So the best I can do is to delete it while reading.

Comment: You're not quite getting it. The reason these characters are being shown as hex codes is either that they are unprintable, and/or they shouldn't be there at all. I think we'd need to know more about the db fields to advise more. For a blunt approach, there are methods in the `Character` class to determine whether a char is a control char. Easily deleted, but what if those details are needed?

Comment: @Andy you seem not  to be reading the answers you are getting. __All characters are unicode__. 'a' is unicode. This comment? 100% unicode. When you say "I want to remove things like unicode" we have no idea what you mean because your understanding of what unicode is isn't right.

Comment: @g00se, Yes you are right these character should not be there at all. The DB field is of type String and it holds a string that has the Unicode string in it. For example: "This is an\u0019 example". I am going take a look at the character methods as you suggested.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, sorry if my comments are confusing. I understand that all character is a Unicode. A is a Unicode, 1 is a unicode, '@' is a unicode. I don't want to remove the Unicode itself because I will be left with nothing, but I want to remove the String that represents the unicode. For instance, \u003F represents a question mark(?). I want remove string like \u003F, not the "question mark" itself. Do you see what I mean? :)

Comment: You misunderstand. That's just how things are rendered. The problem is - that 'character' (unicode 0x19) isn't representable so it's rendered like that. You're going to have to define what you want to remove (example: Just 0x19. Or 'anything that doesn't render - that one is very tricky', or perhaps 'any control character') and we can then help you.

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");` should get rid of that character and any preceding it in terms of character code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @g00se mentioned, the below code removes all not printable characters including `\n \r`

```
input.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");
```

The below code removes, End of Medium unicode string alone.

```
input.replaceAll(unicodeString, "\u0019");
```